# Difference between c.toArray(new String[size]) and c.toArray(new String[] {})

Tags: java, collections, toarray

I can't seem to find an explanation for this. Does `new String[] {}`
provide a more efficient way of providing the type of array?

Answer (score 2):

`new String[] {}` is an empty array, which means `toArray` would have to create a new String array in order to convert the Collection to an array (unless the Collection is empty, in which case `toArray` can simply return the empty array that was passed to it).

In most cases `c.toArray(new String[c.size()])`, which passes the array instance that would be returned by the method, would be slightly more efficient, since one less array object is instantiated compared to `c.toArray(new String[] {})`.

Comment: So `new String[] {}` is the same as `new String[0]`? How are these the same?

Comment: Rather, what is the concept behind the first method, so I can read more about it?

Comment: @halecommarachel `new String[] {}` is exactly the same as `new String[0]`. `new String[] {"x","y","z"}` is a way to instantiate an array without specifying its length explicitly. If you use an empty array `{}` in this initialization, it creates an array of 0 length.

Comment: @halecommarachel Are you asking about the concept behind this type of array instantiation? It's just one of the ways Java allows you to instantiate an array. It's similar to `String[] arr = {"aa","bb","vv"};`

Comment: I was just reading the Java trail on arrays and it initializes an array without using `new`, i.e. `String[] sa = {"hello", "world"}`. Do you know if that's a new shortcut or something?

Comment: Yeah okay the trail doesn't show that method

Comment: @halecommarachel There's a difference between initializing an array in the same line it is declared (no need for `new`) and initializing it after it's already declared or passing an array to a method without first declaring a variable for it (both require `new`).

Comment: Got it, thanks for going into that for me.